# What defines an armor?

Tags: dnd-5e, armor, armor-class

There are some spells and perks that require not having armor on to work, so how is armor defined?

Is it just any equippable gear that has additional AC? Is it anything more durable than regular fabric (like leather)?

Mechanically speaking, if I start wearing something that boosts my AC, like a single gauntlet, would that end Stone's Durability, Mage Armor, or Unarmored Defense?

Comment: Related: [Does Mage Armor count as armor for the monk's class features?](https://rpg.stackexchange.com/questions/55962/does-mage-armor-count-as-armor-for-the-monks-class-features), [Is a Shield considered to be Armor when addressing Armor Proficiency?](https://rpg.stackexchange.com/questions/93706/is-a-shield-considered-to-be-armor-when-addressing-armor-proficiency), [Do Bracers of Defense stack with Mage Armor?](https://rpg.stackexchange.com/questions/125442/do-bracers-of-defense-stack-with-mage-armor) (this last one is directly relevant to your last question)

Comment: (Also, note that "a single bracer/gauntlet" wouldn't give you any benefit, assuming it's one of a pair like the Bracers of Defense. You'd need both.)

Comment: I changed Unarmored Defence to Unarmored Defense. Normally I wouldn't be so picky about American vs English spelling ([both are fine on RPG.SE](https://rpg.meta.stackexchange.com/q/3224/35259)), but technically "[Unarmored Defense](https://www.dndbeyond.com/characters/classes/barbarian#UnarmoredDefense)" is the name of a class feature, so I thought it best to preserve the feature's spelling.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

## Armor refers to a set of armor

Armor is always referred to in sets. Taking the general description of Heavy Armor from the PHB (pg. 145):

> Of all the armor categories, heavy armor offers the best protection. These **suits of armor** cover the entire body and are designed to stop a wide range of attacks.

Also Plate armor specifically, as an example, from the PHB (pg. 145):

> ***Plate.*** Plate consists of shaped, interlocking metal plates to cover the entire body. **A suit of plate includes gauntlets, heavy leather boots, a visored helmet, and thick layers of padding underneath the armor.**

Finally, from PHB (pg. 146), the section on Getting Into and Out of Armor says this for donning armor:

> ***Don.*** This is the time it takes to put on armor. **You benefit from the armor's AC only if** you take the full time to don the **suit of armor**.

From this, it appears to me as though armor is supposed to be worn as a suit, and wearing a single gauntlet wouldn't affect your AC at all.

Therefore, no, wearing a gauntlet won't end the Mage Armor spell or interfere with Unarmored Defense or anything like that, since it doesn't affect your AC.

---

As an aside, some playable races (such as Lizardfolk from *Volo's Guide to Monsters*) have "natural armor", and according to [this answer](https://rpg.stackexchange.com/q/53498/35259) to a question about natural armor and Unarmored Defense, natural armor isn't compatible with Unarmored Defense, Mage Armor, etc. as it calculates AC differently.

Comment: Comments are not for extended discussion; this conversation has been [moved to chat](https://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/94490/discussion-on-answer-by-nathans-what-defines-an-armor).