# Can you use a magic item for its magical property without the proper proficiency?

Tags: dnd-5e, magic-items, proficiency

Can a character have a magic shield and benefit from its magical effect but not its use as a shield when they do not have shield proficiency?

Like wear the shield on their back or something?

If it helps, the item I am thinking about specifically is the Sentinel Shield, which gives advantage on initiative and perception checks.

Comment: related - [What is the point of a shield proficiency?](https://rpg.stackexchange.com/questions/93691/)

Answer (score 17, accepted):

In the description of the sentinel shield it says "While holding this shield..." (DMG page 199) so you must be holding the shield, not just have it on your back. From a quick glance, many other shields have this condition also.

However, you CAN still use a shield that you aren't proficient with but "you have disadvantage on any ability check, saving throw, or attack roll that involves Strength or Dexterity, and you can’t cast spells" (PHB page 144)

Comment: "holding" isn't the same as "wielding" tho. PHB calls it wielding - "Wielding a shield increases your Armar Class by 2" (PHB page 144)

Comment: @enkryptor yes but in the sentence before that it says a shield 'is carried in one hand' (PHB page 144). Hold and carry are the same and the only difference between them and wield is that wield implies use or intent to use

Comment: Also may be worthwhile to note that donning/doffing shields requires a full action and you can't quickly drop it as a free action should you need that hand (for casting, components, attacking, etc.)

Comment: "Hold and carry are the same" - no they aren't. PHB uses the word "carry" both for wielding and having an item in a backpack. - "Your Strength score limits the amount of gear you can *carry*. " (p. 14)

Comment: Moreover, the PHB explicitly distincts "holding" and "carrying", see page 236 - "If another creature is holding *or* carrying the item ...". I suppose "to hold" means (in context) "to have it in your hand(s)" and "carry" means "to have it in your inventory".

Comment: PH Errata also supports that "holding" a weapon isn't wielding - "***Two-Handed (p. 147)***. This property is relevant only when you attack with the weapon, not when you simply hold it." - 
https://media.wizards.com/2016/downloads/DND/PH-Errata-V1.pdf - so you can hold a 2H-weapon in one hand (regardless of your proficiencies), but you need two hands (and a proficiency) to wield it properly

Answer (score 4):

#### The shield must still be worn in the intended fashion.

Magical shields in particular must be worn properly to benefit from their magical properties:

> *Using a magic item’s properties might mean wearing or wielding it.* A magic item meant to be worn must be donned in the intended fashion: boots go on the feet, gloves on the hands, hats and helmets on the head, and rings on the finger. Magic armor must be donned, *a shield strapped to the arm*, a cloak fastened about the shoulders. A weapon must be held in hand.

So the Sentinel Shield *must* be donned properly to benefit from its magical properties, which you can do without being proficient, but you will suffer the penalty:

> If you wear armor that you lack proficiency with, you have disadvantage on any ability check, saving throw, or attack roll that involves Strength or Dexterity, and you can't cast spells.